# How iterate over custom collection that implements IEnumerator<T>?

Tags: c#, loops, ienumerable

I want to iterate over the values of my custom collection using C#.

I created a collection named `MyLinkedList` to represent a custom linked list like this

```
public class MyLinkedList<T> : IEnumerable<T?> where T : IEquatable<T?>
{
    // other methods are removed for simplicity. 

    IEnumerator<T?> IEnumerable<T?>.GetEnumerator()
        => new MyLinkedListNodeEnumerator<T>(_root);

    public IEnumerator GetEnumerator()
        => new MyLinkedListNodeEnumerator<T>(_root);
}
```

I implemented the `IEnumerable<T?>` interface, so I can use `foreach` loop to iterate over the values in my custom collection. Here is the implementation of `MyLinkedListNodeEnumerator`

```
public class MyLinkedListNodeEnumerator<T>(MyLinkedListNode<T>? root)
    : IEnumerator<T?> where T : IEquatable<T?>
{
    private readonly MyLinkedListNode<T>? _root = root;

    private MyLinkedListNode<T>? _current = root;

    public object? Current
    {
        get
        {
            var current = _current;

            _current = _current!.Next;

            return current;
        }
    }

    T? IEnumerator<T?>.Current
    {
        get
        {
            var current = _current;

            _current = _current!.Next;

            return current!.Data;
        }
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {

    }

    public bool MoveNext()
        => _current?.Next != null;

    public void Reset()
    {
        _current = _root;
    }
}
```

Here is a use case example,

```
var list = new MyLinkedList<int>();
list.InsertFirst(10);
list.InsertNext(20);
list.InsertNext(30);
```

When I loop over the Enumerator object, I am expecting that each item to be of `int` type since that is the generic type to create the list. So the `foreach` is using `IEnumerator GetEnumerator()` not `IEnumerable<T?>.GetEnumerator()`.

```
foreach(var item in list) 
{
    // here item is an object of a type MyLinkedListNode<int> 
    // not int as I am expecting.
}
```

How do I ensure that `foreach` will use `IEnumerable<T?>.GetEnumerator()` so I can iterate over `int` values instead?

Comment: Your enumerator is weird. Why is `Current` declared as `object`? Why is your `MoveNext()` not moving at all? Why is `Current` doing the move? These are not the appropriate semantics for a .NET enumerator. Also, your collection's `GetEnumerator` shouldn't return a non generic enumerator.

Comment: Given that `_current` is of type `MyLinkedListNode<T>`, and you `return current;`, no wonder that you are returning `MyLinkedListNode<T>` and not `T`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without knowing the specifics of your `MyLinkedListNode`:

```cs
public class MyLinkedListNodeEnumerator<T> : IEnumerator<T>
{
    private MyLinkedListNode<T> _root;
    private MyLinkedListNode<T> _current = null;

    public MyLinkedListNodeEnumerator(MyLinkedListNode<T> root)
        => _root = root;

    public T Current
        => _current.Data;

    object IEnumerator.Current
        => _current.Data;

    public bool MoveNext()
    {
        _current = _current is null ? _root : _current.Next;
        return _current is not null;
    }

    public void Reset()
        => _current = null;

    public void Dispose()
    { }
}
```

Note that `Current` is idempotent and should not modify the enumerator. The only way to move the enumerator forward is using `MoveNext`. In the initial state, the enumerator is supposed to start *before* the first element which is why `_current` starts at `null`. Also, accessing `Current` without a previous successful `MoveNext` call is not defined.

---

In order for your enumerator to be generic by default, you should swap around your implementation of `IEnumerable<T>`:

```cs
public class MyLinkedList<T> : IEnumerable<T>
{
    // …

    // generic version is public without an explicit implementation
    public IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator()
        => new MyLinkedListNodeEnumerator<T>(_root);

    // explicit implementation on the non-generic one
    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
        => new MyLinkedListNodeEnumerator<T>(_root);
}
```

Comment: yes I updated the MoveNext logic as @Etienne de Martel pointed in his comment. But `foreach(var item list)` var is `object?` not `int`. I have to cast it to int. Is there a way var would be int not object to avoid boxing?

Comment: @Jay The type of your `foreach` variable will be the type of `Current`. In your question, you declare `Current` as being `object?`, hence why.

Comment: @Jay Swap around your definition of `GetEnumerator` to return a generic one by default. See the update to my answer.

Comment: @EtiennedeMartel `IEnumerator<T?>` inherits from `IEnumerator` so it forces you to implement both `object? Current` and `IEnumerator<T?>.Current` but the for each uses IEnumerator.Current` instead of `IEnumerator<T?>.Current`

Comment: @Jay It forces you to implement both, yes, but you chose to implement `IEnumerator<T>`'s version explicitly, which causes problems. You should do it like @poke's answer does. The foreach will use whichever `Current` is accessible, which is the one that _isn't_ explicitly declared (the one without the type in front of `Current`).

Comment: Oh! I got it now. It worked now as expected. Thanks